# eml file display using php not showing images

Tags: php, email, eml

I'm using this code for display eml file contests using php

It shows email body fine but it not displaying the attached images.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$EML_FILE_PATH = '';
$PICTURE_DIRECTORY_PATH = 'img/';

$filename = 'sample.eml';
$eml_file = $EML_FILE_PATH . $filename;

// Improved error handling when opening and reading the file.
if (!$handle = fopen($eml_file, 'r')) {
    die('Cannot open file (' . $eml_file . ')');
}
$content = fread($handle, filesize($eml_file));
fclose($handle);

if ($content === false) {
    die('Error reading file (' . $eml_file . ')');
}

// Define separators for different sections of the email.
if (strpos($content, '------_') !== false) {
    $separator = '------_';
} else {
    $separator = '------=_';
}
$aContent = explode($separator, $content);

$aImages = array();
$thisHTMLContent = '';

foreach ($aContent as $thisContent) {
    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: text/html') !== false) {
        // Correct handling of the email HTML body.
        $thisContent = substr($thisContent, strpos($thisContent, '<!DOCTYPE'));
        $thisHTMLContent = quoted_printable_decode($thisContent);
    }

    // Function to process images (DRY principle).
    function processImage($thisContent, $imgType) {
        $begin = strpos($thisContent, 'Content-ID: <') + 13;
        $long = strpos(substr($thisContent, $begin), '>');
        $img_id = substr($thisContent, $begin, $long);
        $img_name = substr($thisContent, strpos($thisContent, 'name="') + 6, strpos($thisContent, ".$imgType\"") - strpos($thisContent, 'name="') - 6);
        $img_location = $img_name; // Simplified logic assuming name is used as location.
        $searched = 'Content-ID: <' . $img_id . '>';
        $Content_ID_pos = strpos($thisContent, $searched);
        $img_base64 = substr($thisContent, $Content_ID_pos + strlen($searched) + 1);
        return array('id' => $img_id, 'name' => $img_name, 'location' => $img_location, 'type' => $imgType, 'base64' => $img_base64);
    }

    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: image/gif;') !== false) {
        $aImages[] = processImage($thisContent, 'gif');
    }
    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: image/jpeg;') !== false) {
        $aImages[] = processImage($thisContent, 'jpg');
    }
}

foreach ($aImages as $image) {
    $imageData = 'data:image/' . $image['type'] . ';base64,' . trim($image['base64']);
    $thisHTMLContent = str_replace('cid:' . $image['id'], $imageData, $thisHTMLContent);
}

echo $thisHTMLContent;
?>
```

after body ends it shows this kind of texts but not displays the images

```
--0000000000003cea95058bbee080-- --0000000000003cea99058bbee082 Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="=?UTF-8?B?16rXnNeV16DXlCDXqNen15XXkdenINeh16jXp9eZ15Qu? =?UTF-8?B?anBn?=" Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?16rXnNeV16DXlCDXqNen15XXkdenINeh16jXp9eZ15QuanBn?=" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 X-Attachment-Id: f_jx4j1uzv0 Content-ID: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASwBLAAD/4RDqRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgALAAIAAAAmAAAIYgESAAMA AAABAAMAAAExAAIAAAAmAAAIiAEyAAIAAAAUAAAIrodpAAQAAAABAAAIwuocAAcAAAgMAAAAVgAA AAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

at the end it shows like this

[image]

can someone help me to figure out the issue, becoz im using shared server i cant use php libraries or packages

Comment: The main mail body seems to use a local link to the attached file of some kind. Could you disclose more of the mail, how the image is referenced?

Comment: sorry due to privacy issue i cant share full details of email contents

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and I finally got this resolved by inspecting the base64 image string. In my case the base64 string which the function processImage() was returning had additional redundant string "--000000000000c387400611a9d71b--" concatenated to it. So, I tried fixing it by detecting the "--" position from base64 string and cleaning the base64 string without this redundant string.

Modified code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$EML_FILE_PATH = '';

$filename = 'sample-2.eml';
$eml_file = $EML_FILE_PATH . $filename;

// Improved error handling when opening and reading the file.
if (!$handle = fopen($eml_file, 'r')) {
    die('Cannot open file (' . $eml_file . ')');
}
$content = fread($handle, filesize($eml_file));
fclose($handle);

if ($content === false) {
    die('Error reading file (' . $eml_file . ')');
}

// Define separators for different sections of the email.
if (strpos($content, '------_') !== false) {
    $separator = '------_';
} else {
    $separator = '------=_';
}
$aContent = explode($separator, $content);

$aImages = array();
$thisHTMLContent = '';

// Function to process images (DRY principle).
function processImage($thisContent, $imgType) {
    $begin = strpos($thisContent, 'Content-ID: <') + 13;
    $long = strpos(substr($thisContent, $begin), '>');
    $img_id = substr($thisContent, $begin, $long);
    $img_name = substr($thisContent, strpos($thisContent, 'name="') + 6, strpos($thisContent, ".$imgType\"") - strpos($thisContent, 'name="') - 6);
    $img_location = $img_name; // Simplified logic assuming name is used as location.
    $searched = 'Content-ID: <' . $img_id . '>';
    $Content_ID_pos = strpos($thisContent, $searched);
    $img_base64 = substr($thisContent, $Content_ID_pos + strlen($searched) + 1);
    //redundant  part detection
    $redunantPart = "--";
    //redundant part position taken out
    $redunantParPos = strpos($img_base64, $redunantPart);
    //base64 string is cleaned
    $img_base64_clean = substr($img_base64, 0, $redunantParPos);
    //final return of the  new string
    return array('id' => $img_id, 'name' => $img_name, 'location' => $img_location, 'type' => $imgType, 'base64' => $img_base64_clean);
}

foreach ($aContent as $thisContent) {
    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: text/html') !== false) {
        // Correct handling of the email HTML body.
        $thisContent = substr($thisContent, strpos($thisContent, '<!DOCTYPE'));
        $thisHTMLContent = quoted_printable_decode($thisContent);
    }

    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: image/gif;') !== false) {
        $aImages[] = processImage($thisContent, 'gif');
    }
    if (strpos($thisContent, 'Content-Type: image/jpeg;') !== false) {
        $aImages[] = processImage($thisContent, 'jpg');
    }
}
// Output the image using data URI
$finalImage = '';
foreach ($aImages as $image) {
    $finalImage .= '<img src="data:image/' . $image['type'] . ';base64,' . trim($image['base64']) . '" />';
}
```

Comment: _"had additional redundant string `--000000000000c387400611a9d71b--` concatenated to it"_ - that sounds like it was the final _boundary_ value, so that would mean you did not decode the multipart message body _correctly_ to begin with. (Probably not too much of a surprise, with all that substring hackery.)